# PCI compliance in existing Notes documents with Lotusscript

Tags: lotusscript, pci-dss

I am trying to X out all creditcard numbers in a Lotus Notes database.
They are located in customer emails within a customer database with more than 80.000 documents.
So my issue is to remove data (creditcard data) from "older" documents.

My progress so far:
I have been able to take each document in the database utilizing regular expression and actually find creditcards. Even managed to replace many.

Problem: 
1) The rich text field may consist of attachments, and other issues that return in error handling "type mismatch" et al. 
2) I am in a time squeeze so I got no time for trial and error. (Even tried to get in touch with Geniie software to no avail)

Question:
Is there anyone who got experience with the challenge above, who could help med out. 
Even for a reward :-)

Comment: Minor but important comment: remember to encrypt and restrict access to that database :-) (due to PCI compliance)

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you unless you post your code and give specific examples of lines that generate type mismatch.  As for attachments, you would have to detach them, read them, modify them, and replace them.  And of course, they could be in any format at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getFormattedText/getUnformattedText on the rich-text-field via LotusScript, so you can read the text without any care of attachments

Comment: Is there no one who is interested in selling an working Lotusscript agent performing PCI ASAP?

Comment: You can contact me for this case, but I would need some further information to accomplish the task - eMail is in my profile

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. 1. Do you got a finished script available? 2. Your email adress is not visible, I hope mine is.

Comment: Hi! Ok, no I don't see your mail neither - juergen.starkl@gmail.com! 1) No out of the box solution! - Provide me a sample-database with some sample date (please-no real data), so that I can implement the function